# Mapserver's mapfile

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

Is there possible to load a mapfile file from a client  to a server running a Mapserver?
e.g.  **http://server/cgi-bin/mapserv?**map=**client**/example/htdocs/example1-1.map&layer=states&mode=map

Comment: No, it is not possible and that's good. Mapfile contains all the details for making a connection with a database and through DATA line your users could inject whatever SQL into your system. Validation blocks would not help because users could edit them too and make the evil SQL to validate.

Comment: However, I suppose you can do what you want with server side MapScript http://mapserver.org/mapscript/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

No. You may create a form for file upload from the browser, but you need server side script to process uploaded data or you can use ftp/scp to upload files to the server.